# Big troubles with easy multiprocessing code: runtime error (python)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, runtime-error, python-multiprocessing

I wrote an easy code in Python just to learn how to use multiprocessing. So I defined a scrap function:

```
def useless_function(exp):
    for j in range(int(10**exp):
        pass
```

If I execute a code like the following, the first for loop works, the second leads the pc to pure madness:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def useless_function(exp):
    for j in range(int(10**exp)):
        pass

exp=8
start=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(5):
    useless_function(exp)
    print("No multiprocessing, I got to iteration ",i)

middle=time.perf_counter()
print("No multiproc., process ended in ",middle-start," seconds.")

if __name__=="__main__":
    processes=[]
    for j in range(5):
        p=mp.Process(target=useless_function,args=(exp,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
        print("WITH multiproc. I got to step ",processes.index(process))
    finish=time.perf_counter()
    print("With multiproc. process ended in ",finish-middle," seconds.")
```

And the output I get is pretty odd: it looks like the multiprocess part goes back to the non-parallelized *for loop* and executes it. How can it even go back in the code?

```
No multiproc., I got to iteration  0
No multiproc., I got to iteration  1
No multiproc., I got to iteration  2
No multiproc., I got to iteration  3
No multiproc., I got to iteration  4
No multiproc., process ended in  9.914604499999996  seconds.
No multiproc., I got to iteration  0
No multiproc., I got to iteration  0
No multiproc., I got to iteration  0
No multiproc., I got to iteration  0
No multiproc., I got to iteration  0
No multiproc., I got to iteration  1
No multiproc., I got to iteration  1
No multiproc., I got to iteration  1
No multiproc., I got to iteration  1
No multiproc., I got to iteration  1
No multiproc., I got to iteration  2
No multiproc., I got to iteration  2
No multiproc., I got to iteration  2
No multiproc., I got to iteration  2
No multiproc., I got to iteration  2
No multiproc., I got to iteration  3
No multiproc., I got to iteration  3
No multiproc., I got to iteration  3
No multiproc., I got to iteration  3
No multiproc., I got to iteration  3
No multiproc., I got to iteration  4
No multiproc., process ended in  25.363089899999977  seconds.
No multiproc., I got to iteration  4
No multiproc., process ended in  25.52356009999994  seconds.
No multiproc., I got to iteration  4
No multiproc., process ended in  25.786010900000065  seconds.
No multiproc., I got to iteration  4
No multiproc., process ended in  25.977586800000154  seconds.
No multiproc., I got to iteration  4
No multiproc., process ended in  27.87371519999988  seconds.
WITH multiproc. I got to step  0
WITH multiproc. I got to step  1
WITH multiproc. I got to step  2
WITH multiproc. I got to step  3
WITH multiproc. I got to step  4
With multiproc. process ended in  32.527025200000026  seconds.
```

No error message, just nonsense. What should I do?

Comment: please include the full error message you get by editing your post

Comment: What is exp in your loop? It's not defined...

Comment: How do you expect this program to run?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I hope my question is clearer after editing the post. I tried using the if name__=='__main__' as the error message suggests, but did not work

Comment: Could you please show the code how did you use `if main`? It should resolve the problem actually

Comment: @kosciej16 I have uploaded the whole code, sorry for not doing it before

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's hard to notice it in the documentation, but there is as secion about how [process is run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods).

Generally on linux processes are spawn by `fork` command which shares resources with parent. It would work as you expect here. However Windows has no such kernel support and it uses `spawn`, so run your **.py** script again for each process - that's why without `if name == __main__` it causes error and that's why you see your file level functions are run many times.

In your case it will be enough to put file level loop to a function.

[Here](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/differences-between-multiprocessing-windows-and-linux/) and [here](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2010/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows/) I found useful blogs that can give you more insight.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since I want a code executable both on windows and linux I decided to turn to *joblib* library, it worked for me.